Plugin for Android Application is Unable to Locate Service
my team and I are working on a plugin for the Android app CivTAK. Plugins in the context of this application are treated as individual apps with just a Service and no Activity that are discovered by the main application with specific Intent it looks for.
We are attempting to integrate the Reticulum Network Stack into CivTAK as part of our senior design project and originally tried to work entirely within the plugin, but ultimately ran into conflicts between its environment and the bridge we used to integrate the Python based network stack, Chaquopy.
This lead to us investigating how similar plugins dealt with the issue and saw that Meshtastic handles it by having their CivTAK plugin bind to a remote Foreground Service spawned by their Android app that hosts the network stack
We decided to pursue this approach and began developing a separate app based on their approach to spawn the Service that'll host RNS. The app boots successfully and does instantiate the service based off of what occurs in the debugger and feedback from logcat; it also appears in the service list on our Android 12 phones (but not our Android 13 ones).
When the CivTAK plugin attempts to bind to the Service bindService returns false and logcat displays an error stating

Unable to start service Intent { cmp="com.ed2group.RTAKService/.RNSService } U=0: not found

Service app MainActivity
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, RNSService.class);
        startForegroundService(intent);
        finish();
    }
}

Service app Foreground Service onCreate
package com.ed2group.RTAKService;

public class RNSService extends android.app.Service {
// Stripped out Binder Stub definitions, members, and assistive methods

@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        try {
            // RNS & misc initialization code.

            startForeground(21124, createNotification());

            Log.i(TAG, "onCreate: Initialization successful!");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: ", e);
        }
    }

Service app AndroidManifest.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.ed2group.RTAKService">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_CONNECTED_DEVICE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_SPECIAL_USE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />

    <application
        android:name="com.chaquo.python.android.PyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.RTAKService">

        <activity android:name="com.ed2group.RTAKService.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="com.ed2group.RTAKService.RNSService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:foregroundServiceType="connectedDevice|specialUse"
            android:exported="true"
            tools:ignore="ExportedService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="RNSService"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>
</manifest>

CivTAK plugin Service binding point snippet
rtakServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
                Toast.makeText(mapView.getContext(), "Successfully connected to RTAKService", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                rtakService = IRNSService.Stub.asInterface(iBinder);
                isConnected = true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
                Toast.makeText(mapView.getContext(), "Disconnected from RTAKService", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                rtakService = null;
                isConnected = false;
            }
        };

        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent();
        serviceIntent.setClassName("com.ed2group.RTAKService", ".RNSService");

        if (!pluginContext.bindService(serviceIntent, rtakServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)) {
                Toast.makeText(mapView.getContext(), "Failed to connect to RTAKService", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
        }


CivTAK plugin AndroidManifest.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:description="@string/app_desc"
        android:extractNativeLibs="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data
            android:name="plugin-api"
            android:value="${atakApiVersion}" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="app_desc"
            android:value="@string/app_desc" />
        <!--
 This fictitious activity entry allow for ATAK 4.6.0.2 and newer to perform
            plugin discovery  android devices.  If this is removed, the plugin will
            not be able to be discovered or loaded.
        -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.atakmap.app.component"
            android:exported="true"
            tools:ignore="MissingClass">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
                <action android:name="com.atakmap.app.component" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <queries>
        <package android:name="com.ed2group.RTAKService" />
    </queries>
</manifest>

If any more examples are required please do not be afraid to ask for them or I can link you to our repositories.
I have tried to follow multiple resources regarding bound Services that I could find from Google, Reddit, and YouTube, but the error would still remain the same. I have also experimented with just making it a regular background service, but not no avail as well.
Any help in getting our plugin to link with our Service would be greatly appreciated, TYVM.
